# Getting "there is no attribute 'REL'" on favicon tag when trying to validate page

Tags: html, favicon, w3c-validation

When I try to validate my page using the [W3C validation service](http://validator.w3.org/), I'm getting this error:

```
Error  Line 13, Column 11: there is no attribute "REL"

<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico" />
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: the attribute is `rel`, not `REL`

Comment: <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="favicon.ico" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code I'm using on my site:

```
<link href="http://www.mysite.com/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

It works and is valid according to http://validator.w3.org/.

I think the main problem with your code is that you're using uppercase letters. Use lowercase letters instead.

Since your favicon probably is used on many pages, I also suggest you use the full adress, like in the code above, so that all files on your site can find the favicon no matter what folder they are in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed with

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```